# customize Java heap size on Google Compute Engine instances

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jvm, google-compute-engine, heap-size

I have an application that is compute intensive (it does some numerical methods operations, so there is normal to have this big consumption of heap size by this code) and when ran on Google App Engine it throws: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". Even Google App Engine pretends to automatically scale to suit app requirements, that does not happen in regard to heap size. I tried then to create some instances on Google Compute Engine, such as "16 VCPU's with 60 GB memory" and still get that error, because I suspect the heap size used even by this instance is less than 1 GB. So my question is: how can I customize the heap size on Google Compute Instances or Google App Engine so I can set a heap size of 2 GB?

Thanks

Sorin

Answer (score 0):

On Google App Engine, you're [limited to 1GB of RAM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/?hl=en#Java_Instance_scaling_and_class) on the largest insurance types, so if you need more than 1GB RAM, you'll need to use Compute Engine or the [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/hello-world).

When running on a VM, you'll want to set [the -Xmx and -Xms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/sizing.html#sthref22) flags to control the maximum and minimum heap sizes, respectively.

Note that you may need to use `java64` to be able to use more than 4GB of RAM.

Comment: So, for Google App Engine the maximum RAM is 1 GB but how much is reserved for JVM heap? Also, for GAE is it possible to do any customization of the heap size, or that is not available for the end-user?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the max heap size on GAE is 1GB. This parameter is not customizable and is controlled by the GAE runtime.

Comment: The link that you posted in your original answer "limited to 1 GB of RAM" is broken, can you please post a valid reference link?